# electric field inside a hollow ball and the Gauss's law

Tags: gauss-law

I am wondering about the answer to the PSE question here:  [Electric Field inside a hollow ball, excentred of a homogeneous charged ball](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54789/9887)

I understand the solution, but I don't understand how it corresponds to the Gauss's law. The charge inside the hollow is equal to zero, so why isn't the electric field?

Comment: Where on that page do you see that the field is nonzero inside the hollow?

Comment: It is not written there, but it is certainly nonzero ;)

Comment: Oh, the hollow is displaced from the center.

Comment: -1. On this site it is considered a bad practice to post "link only" questions or answers. If the linked material is deleted then your question becomes incomprehensible. You should always summarise the essential information from the link in your own question.

Comment: @sammygerbil, the link is to a question on this site (if it makes any difference).

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Yes, I am aware of that. But the question could still be deleted. Also, it should not be necessary to examine a link in order to understand what a question is asking.

Answer (score 1):

The superposition principle tells us that the field due to the two objects (a fully charged sphere, and a smaller sphere with opposite charge density) can be added together. It is entirely possible to have a non-zero electric field in a region without any charge in it (think for example about the space between the plates of a parallel plate capacitor). You just need a field whose *divergence* is zero, that is $\nabla \cdot E = 0$. This is true, for example, for a uniform field, or a field of the form $e\propto \frac{1}{r}$ .

The absence of a charge does not imply the absence of field - just the absence of divergence.

Answer (score 1):

> but I don't understand how it corresponds to the Gauss's law.

Gauss' law tells you that the electric flux through the surface that defines the hollow volume is zero since the charge enclosed is zero.

But that doesn't imply that the electric field is *zero* within the hollow volume only that the electric field is *special* in the sense that *all* of the field lines *entering* the volume *leave* the volume since there is no electric charge there on which electric field lines originate and/or terminate.

That is, as Floris points out, the electric field within the hollow volume has zero divergence.